# Get WebCam deviceids and info from c# through WMI

Tags: c#, wmi, webcam

How do I get info about the connected video device / webcam through WMI?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to search [**WMI Samples**](http://www.activexperts.com/activmonitor/windowsmanagement/wmi/samples/) website for info you need. Also [**WMI code creator**](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=2cc30a64-ea15-4661-8da4-55bbc145c30e&displaylang=en) may help you by allowing to browse local computer for WMI classes, and maybe you will find how to extract information you need